# Y-dna upgrade or SNP pack?

Tags: dna, y-dna, 23andme, haplogroup

I took the Y-dna12 test first, it came out as J-M67 but I want to proceed to find out my subclade and I can't decide to either get the J2 - M67 & L24 SNP Pack or to upgrade to Y-DNA67. What would be more beneficial in terms of results. What would you suggest?

Nevgen says i'm 96% J2A1 L26>Z500 and the SNP pack does include Z500 so Im good on that but then again maybe the upgrade will reveal more information?

I spoke to 2 project leaders, one is telling me to get the SNP pack the other is really pushing me to get the upgrade to unlock more matches on the FTDNA database and he says the upgrade results would be the same same or even better than that from SNP pack. He actually wants me to get the full-Y but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The Big-Y will definitively answer this question. With the other tests you might not find out what you want to know. Plus the Big-Y tests for known and unknown Y SNPs, not just a few known ones. Your test could advance our general knowledge of the Y-DNA haplogroup tree.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you’ve not tested at 23AndMe, or LivingDNA, as they can report the [rs13447376 = A,A (J2A1 membership)](https://www.snpedia.com/index.php/Rs13447376). Similarly you’ve not exported a copy of say an AncestryDNA raw file, and manually checked, or via the likes of [Promethease](https://www.snpedia.com/index.php/Promethease), for that mutation, of many a downstream set, eg. [SNPedia - Y-Haplogroup to SNP to tester](https://www.snpedia.com/index.php?title=Special:Ask&limit=500&offset=8&q=%5B%5BCategory%3AIs%20a%20snp%5D%5D%20%5B%5BFlag%3A%3AHaplogroup%5D%5D&p=mainlabel%3D%2Fformat%3Dtable&po=%3FOn%20microarray%0A%3FIn%20gene%0A%3FChromosome%20position%0A&sort=&order=asc&eq=no#search)

If you’ve got a genotyped Data file to hand I’d suggest you try a lookup, as an instant, free test. Then is specifically after claiming membership of a specific Haplogroup, go for the SNP pack, or Big-Y upgrade, else if trying to filter your numerous 0 distant matches, at 12 markers, and possibly acquiring a more refined, but guesstimated Y-Haplogroup, a Y-111 upgrade. As I’m sure you’re aware STR guesstimate, while SNP value sets call a Haplogroup.